# extIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program to create an id pw using files.

Here is my code:

```py
n = input("enter your name")
print("Enter Your Password:-")

f = open("user_ids.txt", "a")
f.write(n, "\n")
f.write(p1)
f.close()
```

Running this code displays the following error:

```
extIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: f.write(n+'\n') is probably what you meant

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass multiple arguments into the write function.

As Andy Knight said, you probably meant `f.write(n+"\n")`, as this will write the vale of `n`, followed by a new line.

In python, the print statement lets you pass in the string as multiple arguments *(`print("ABC","DEF")` prints `ABC DEF`)*, but you can't do this with many other functions, so be careful.